# SQL: Getting the “first” item of a joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

Let’s say I want to show a list of companies, and also a first/random employee of that company.

I could do something like:

```
SELECT
  company.id,
  company.name,
  MIN(person.id) AS employee_person_id,
  MIN(person.name) AS employee_person_name
FROM company
LEFT OUTER JOIN person ON (person.company_id = company.id)
GROUP BY company.id;
```

But I think with my code above, `MIN(person.id)` and `MIN(person.name)` could give info about two different people, right?

Is there a better way of retrieving just a “first” (or random) employee and showing that person’s ID and name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct:

> MIN(person.id) and MIN(person.name) could give info about two different people, right?

You can see that happening in the demo linked below.

[GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75743006/5298879)'s [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) is typically the most recommended, obvious choice, but it requires ordering, same as [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75742859/5298879)'s. Meanwhile, you can let [each](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) company *just get [any single](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) `person`*, without having to order them first: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GI_1r0Ro)

```sql
SELECT company.id, company.name, person.id, person.name
FROM company LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(SELECT id,name FROM person WHERE company_id=company.id LIMIT 1) person
             ON true;
```

Even simpler if you don't have `companies` with no `persons`, or if you ignore such `companies`:

```sql
SELECT company.id, company.name, person.id,  person.name
FROM company, 
LATERAL (SELECT id,name FROM person WHERE company_id=company.id LIMIT 1) person;
```

It's *"retrieving just a “first” (or random) employee"* the convenient way: it takes whatever it happens to find first, without having to find and order all possible matches before picking one. Each company just fetches *any one* of their people, which seemed to be the idea.

Thanks to not doing the extra work, [it's faster (16'000x on 300'000 row sample)](https://dbfiddle.uk/kJDQyULK) and it scales in proportion to only the `company`, pretty much disregarding the `person` table's size and growth.

Comment: Locally I bumped up the `person` test sample to 10M rows and it didn't care, still taking below 0.1milliseconds, while the others jumped to 16 and 25 seconds.

Comment: Yes this does match what the OP asked for (get *any* person from each company), and sure performs better than my deterministic query, +1.

Comment: Awesome reply @Zegarek!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `row_number` window function to assign a numbering within each company, and then use that to query the first person:

```sql
SELECT c_id, c_name, p_id, p_name
FROM   (SELECT    c.id AS c_id,
                  c.name AS c_name,
                  p.id AS p_id,
                  p.name AS p_name,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY p.id ASC) AS rn
        FROM      company c
        LEFT JOIN person p ON p.company_id = c.id) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: The `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` [addition](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75742859/2) from [@UltraCommit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297267/ultracommit) is from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_random.htm#TTPLP040) - won't work in PostgreSQL. In Postgres, use [`random()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE). Either only makes sense if you require semi-reliable randomness. If you just don't care which one you get, it's faster, simpler and more convenient to *not use `order by`*, at all.

Comment: Looks like *not* ordering can save you some (sometimes half) the execution time, but it's still slowed down by collecting all matches before picking the one to return. I've updated [the performance tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75743855/5298879)

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get the correct name :

You will have to join your result with the person table by `person.id = s.employee_person_id`

```
select s.company_id, s.company_name, s.employee_person_id, p.name as employee_person_name
from person p
inner join (
    SELECT
      company.id as company_id,
      company.name as company_name,
      MIN(person.id) AS employee_person_id
    FROM company
    LEFT OUTER JOIN person ON (person.company_id = company.id)
    GROUP BY company.id
) as s on s.employee_person_id = p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
SELECT distinct on (c.id)
  c.id,
  c.name,
  p.id AS employee_person_id,
  p.name AS employee_person_name
FROM company c
LEFT OUTER JOIN person p ON p.company_id = c.id
ORDER BY c.id, p.id
```

For each company, this brings the person with the smallest id; you control which person is picked with the `ORDER BY` clause (if you wanted the person with the greatest id, you would use `ORDER BY c.id, p.id DESC`).

Comment: IMHO this approach is by far the best.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm That would normally be my first choice, too. Still, I think that *retrieving just a “first” (or random) employee* means you can [skip ordering and gain some performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75743855/5298879)

Comment: @Zegarek I cannot but agree.